# take the table element while clicking on the same table element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jruby

I'm developing a project and I have a problem about this subject.

I'm constructing ruby on rails project which will provide listing students with name.

First of all , I will list my students information in a table and one part is missing.

When the user clicks on Student Name , another table will appear and show the other information of students(like course or GPA).

The table shows the students name ( this part is succeed.)

But I don't know how to post my variable when user clicks on the students name.

Moreover , I know fundementals of AJAX.But I don't know how to pass my variable while user clicks on students name in the table.

I don't use form , and I try to fix this problem with link_to_remote method but I can't post my variable.Because I can construct my table in for-loop according to my listing variable which contains whole database.I filter for getting only names and surnames in controller part of ruby on rails and i have listing variable for this.when in for-loop i use <%=student.name%> tag for displaying the part of my variable.and I must post this variable to page for filtering GPA or Course name according to names.I need something like link_to_remote method for posting my variable student.name

I'm waiting your help.

Code is below :

```
    <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>
      Name
    </th>
  </tr>
    <% @listing.each do |student| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <%=student.name%> <%= student.surname %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have fixed that problem.. I used :with keyword with link_to_remote :)

Answer (score 0):

problem fixed ,:with => "'id=blabla'" in link_to_remote method